# Biber not working: incorrect locale settings

Tags: biber, mac

I'm running biber on a new MacBook Pro, and I am struggling to understand the errors I'm getting. When I try to run biber on a beamer handout, I get the following errors:

```
Running `Biber' on `handout' with ``biber handout''
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_DE.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
INFO - This is Biber 2.12
INFO - Logfile is 'handout.blg'
INFO - Reading 'handout.bcf'
INFO - Found 0 citekeys in bib section 0
WARN - The file 'handout.bcf' does not contain any citations!
INFO - Writing 'handout.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
INFO - Output to handout.bbl
INFO - WARNINGS: 1
```

Can anyone help me understand these? Here's an example of a test document

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} % or whatever

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
        bibstyle=biblatex-langsci-unified,
        useprefix=true,
        citestyle=langsci-authoryear-comp,
        maxcitenames=3,
        maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}

This is a test \parencite{kutschlojenga94}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And the bib.bib file contains

```
@Article{kutschlojenga94,
  author =   {Kutsch Lojenga, Constance},
  title =    {Kubudu},
  subtitle =     {A {Bantu} language with nine vowels},
  journal =      {African Languages},
  year =     1994,
  volume =   9,
  pages =    {127--34}}
```

UPDATE: Thanks to those that have been helping. I've added the \addbibresource{bib.bib}. After running LaTeX, biber, LaTeX, LaTeX the .blg file reads

```
[0] Config.pm:304> INFO - This is Biber 2.12
[0] Config.pm:307> INFO - Logfile is 'test.blg'
[47] biber-darwin:315> INFO - === Tue Jul 16, 2019, 10:29:52
[71] Biber.pm:371> INFO - Reading 'test.bcf'
[158] Biber.pm:889> INFO - Found 0 citekeys in bib section 0
[166] Utils.pm:193> WARN - The file 'test.bcf' does not contain any citations!
[173] bbl.pm:636> INFO - Writing 'test.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
[173] bbl.pm:739> INFO - Output to test.bbl
[173] Biber.pm:110> INFO - WARNINGS: 1
```

The .tex, .bib, .blg, and .log files are available on github at https://github.com/JJSandstedt/Biber_issue_stack_exchange

Comment: `en_DE.UTF-8` is a bit of an odd locale (the English spoken in Germany ...) and so it does not surprise me too much that the locale can not be found. A search for `en_DE.UTF-8` leads to https://askubuntu.com/q/710955/57634, which explains what is going on. There is also https://stackoverflow.com/q/44243909 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/9991603 which mention some issues with locales specifically on a Mac. I don't have a Mac, so I can't test, but you may want to double check your system language/locale settings. ...

Comment: ... It would also help if you could provide a minimal example document that you are running. If my hunch is right the locale warning could be benign, but maybe more things go wrong if the locale can't be set ...

Comment: Your system is not correct configured. If you are Linux or macOS then run in. a terminal `export LANG=de_DE.UTF-8`. and then run `biber` in the same terminal.

Comment: Any news here? Could you find out if the error message has any actual relevance? Did you try changing your system locale or define `en_DE.utf8`?

Comment: I have changed the language in system preferences to UK English, and so now it doesn't complain about the locale, but it still always fails to find citekeys. I'm new to this and useless at things with the terminal.

Comment: OK, that is a different issue. To help you with that we need to know what your document looks like. The log file above says `The file 'handout.bcf' does not contain any citations!`, which just suggests that you did not cite anything in your document.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter what document I run it on. And I do include citations, but it's not picking them up. I've edited the example to include a minimal example.

Comment: The example `.tex` file is missing an `\addbibresource` call that tells `biblatex` where to find the references. You should probably add `\addbibresource{bib.bib}` to the preamble. Add that to the MWE and then compile the MWE with  LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (best would be from the command line: `pdflatex mwe`, `biber mwe`, `pdflatex mwe`, `pdflatex mwe`). Upload the `.log` and `.blg` after the compile cycle (the `.log` will likely be too large, so upload it to https://gist.github.com/ or https://pastebin.com/) and only show the relevant bits here.

Comment: Hi moewe, I've edited the post now following your instructions. What do you think? Thanks for the help!

Comment: The new problems have little to do with the original question about locale settings. The LaTeX run throws two errors: `Package biblatex Error: Style 'biblatex-langsci-unified' not found. The bibliography style 'biblatex-langsci-unified' could not be found.` and `Package biblatex Error: Style 'langsci-authoryear-comp' not found. The citation style 'langsci-authoryear-comp' could not be found.` This means that `\cite` will be undefined and that citations will not work. Either install the relevant styles `biblatex-langsci-unified.bbx` and `langsci-authoryear-comp.cbx` or use a different style.

Comment: I have a hunch that the files `biblatex-langsci-unified.bbx` and `langsci-authoryear-comp.cbx` have been renamed to `langsci-authoryear-comp.cbx` and `langsci-authoryear-comp.bbx`, respectively. The files are available in the package [`langsci`](https://ctan.org/pkg/langsci). The `biblatex` styles are based on https://github.com/semprag/biblatex-sp-unified.

Answer (score 1):

The

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
```

is most likely due to your unusual locale settings. You have

```
en_DE.UTF-8
```

which would be "the English spoken in Germany" (or English language with German localisation). Quite probably your system does not have locale definitions for those settings.

Googling for this and similar issues one finds amongst others https://askubuntu.com/q/710955/57634, https://stackoverflow.com/q/44243909 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/9991603.

---

The issue should go away if you select a locale in your language/locale settings that can actually be found (for example US English, UK English, German (Germany) etc.). If you want to stick to `en_DE.utf8` you probably need to define the locale, see the previous links. In any case I expect little problems from this as long as the sorting locales that Biber needs can be found (usually those are selected from the document settings and so your generic settings should not matter).

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't care to keep the en-DE.utf8 locale setting. That's just how this computer came. I'd gladly just have UK English, but how do I change the locale setting? Apparently changing the language settings in System Preferences isn't enough?

Comment: @user9974638 Sorry, I don't own a Mac and can't give you system-specific advice. Did you consider asking at https://apple.stackexchange.com/?