# Biber error on Mac - locale and bibtex subsystem issues

Tags: biber, debugging

Biber runs with this warning:

```
Running `Biber' on `citation_issues' with ``biber citation_issues''
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_TW.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

And this error:

```
WARN - BibTeX subsystem: /var/folders/rw/rpr418x91h13ysbc6k7fzj240000gn/T/XreBNpegVI/thesis.bib_98780.utf8, line 7325, warning: "(" in strange place -- should get a syntax error
ERROR - BibTeX subsystem: /var/folders/rw/rpr418x91h13ysbc6k7fzj240000gn/T/XreBNpegVI/thesis.bib_98780.utf8, line 7325, syntax error: found "(", expected ","
INFO - WARNINGS: 1
INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

Locale settings on the terminal do not concur with what biber reported.

```
$ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

How do we resolve that?

## Tex file:

```
% Created 2019-08-29 Thu 13:25
% Intended LaTeX compiler: xelatex

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
%\usepackage[heading]{CJK}
\usepackage{zhnumber} % package for Chinese formatting of date time (use /zhtoday)
%\usepackage[yyyymmdd]{datetime} % set date time to numeric

% Set default indentation

\setlength\parindent{12pt}

% Set Paper Size, Page Layout (another variable is 'bindingoffset')
\usepackage[margin = 1.5in, paper = a4paper, inner = 2.5cm,
outer = 2.5cm, top = 3cm, bottom = 2.5cm]{geometry}

% Keep paragraph indentation while having a line break in between paragraphs.
\edef\restoreparindent{\parindent=\the\parindent\relax}
\usepackage{parskip}
\restoreparindent

% Indent first paragraph.
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fontspec} % packages for title and section-heading font setting.

% Set Font.
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmainfont{Calibri} % Set serifed font to Calibri. Originally set to 'Times New Roman', but it cannot display certain characters such as ①②③.
\setCJKmainfont{MingLiU}
\setCJKsansfont{Kaiti TC} % Set Chinese font. NOTE: Remember to append CJK before of the font class. CJK HAS to be there for the font to show.

\titleformat*{\section}{\fontsize{16}{18}\bfseries\sffamily}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\fontsize{14}{16}\bfseries\sffamily}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\fontsize{12}{14}\bfseries\sffamily} % Set formats for each heading level. 'sffamily' will point to the sans-serif font. In this case, 「楷體」.
\renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{\sffamily} % Set title font.

% Set quotation font.
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newCJKfontfamily\quotefont{Kaiti TC}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\quotefont\normalsize}

% Tweak default settings.
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2} % Set line width.
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{目次} % Translate content page title to Chinese. (Could possibly be done automatically with '\usepackage[heading]{CJK}'. TODO experiment. )

% For text-boxes

\usepackage{mdframed}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{minted}{\begin{mdframed}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{minted}{\end{mdframed}}

% [FIXME] ox-latex 的設計不良導致 hypersetup 必須在這裡插入
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true, %把紅框框移掉改用字體顏色不同來顯示連結
  linkcolor=[rgb]{0,0.37,0.53},
  citecolor=[rgb]{0,0.47,0.68},
  filecolor=[rgb]{0,0.37,0.53},
  urlcolor=[rgb]{0,0.37,0.53},
  pagebackref=true,
  linktoc=all,}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear-icomp,bibstyle=authoryear, hyperref=true,backref=true,maxcitenames=3,url=true,backend=biber,natbib=true] {biblatex}
\addbibresource{/Users/satibodhi/Creation/notes/bibliography/thesis.bib}
\author{TYH}
\date{\today}
\title{Citation Issues}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

這是一註腳\footnote{\cite{錢穆LunYuXinJie2008}。}，這又是一註腳\footnote{\cite[55-100]{陳鼓應YiChuanYuDaoJiaSiXiang1994}}。

\section{引用書目}
\label{sec:orgf6071a9}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

## Bibtex:

```
@book{錢穆LunYuXinJie2008,
  langid = {Chinese},
  location = {{臺北市}},
  title = {論語新解},
  isbn = {978-957-19-2770-1},
  abstract = {附錄：孔子年表},
  publisher = {{東大出版}},
  date = {2008},
  author = {{錢穆}},
  file = {/Volumes/Seagate/Digital Library/論語新解.pdf},
  note = {OCLC: 858329177}
}

@book{陳鼓應YiChuanYuDaoJiaSiXiang1994,
  langid = {pinyin},
  location = {{台北}},
  title = {易傳與道家思想},
  isbn = {978-957-05-0994-6},
  pagetotal = {382},
  publisher = {{臺灣商務印書館}},
  date = {1994},
  author = {{陳鼓應}},
  eprinttype = {googlebooks}
}
```

---

## Update:

The error above was apparently caused by this `.bib` entry.

```
@article{祝總(又武)LueLunJinLuDe1983,
  title = {略論晉律的``寬簡''和``周備''},
  abstract = {{$<$}正{$>$} 晉律(泰始律)頒布于泰始四年(268),是我國古代一部頗為重要的法典。它旣反映了魏晉時期政治經濟特點,成為鞏固西晉地主階級統治的工具,對太康年間的經濟繁榮起了一定作用;又前承漢律,后啟唐律,影響于后代法律頗大,在我國法制發展史上占有其不可忽視的地位。遺憾的是:晉律早已散佚,比較重要的資料{$\ElsevierGlyph{300A}$}晉書{$\cdot$}刑法志{$\ElsevierGlyph{300B}$}又語焉而不詳。為了有助于晉律之研究,本文試圖就它的``寬簡''和``周備''這兩方面的問題作一些考證和分析,并初步接觸其階級本質和指導思想。拋磚引玉,千慮一得,敬希讀者指正。},
  number = {02},
  journaltitle = {北京大學學報(哲學社會科學版)},
  date = {1983},
  author = {祝總(又武)}
}
```

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/496173/35864

Comment: I don't know where exactly the locale settings come from, but `en_TW.UTF-8` looks a bit fishy.

Comment: A very similar issue is reported at https://stackoverflow.com/q/44243909 and https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/6787 (also https://discourse.brew.sh/t/failed-to-set-locale-category-lc-numeric-to-en-ru/5092) `lang` in the terminal gives a sensible output, but Perl detects a different locale. So I guess it tries to get the locale settings from somewhere else. `en_TW` looks as though your system language is English, but you configured Taiwanese localisation extras (dates, currency, etc.)

Comment: Not sure if the error indicated above is in anyway related to this locale issue.

Comment: Yes, that's true. However, if that is the case, changing system language back to Chinese should cause Perl to switch back to the more normal-looking zh-TW. It did not.

Comment: Indeed the two issues are very likely independent. I can not reproduce the Biber error with the given `.bib` file. Do check if any of your `.bib` entries (especially around line 7325 of the `.bib` file) contains any `(` or `)`. In particular `(` and `)` may not be used in the entry key.

Comment: Aha! `(` and `)` are not allowed, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96454/35864, https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/876 and https://github.com/ambs/Text-BibTeX/issues/30. This behaviour is documented in the `biblatex` manual (p. 161 for `biblatex` v3.13).

Comment: Removing parentheses from the bibtex key is not an issue for me, so long as I know it is the cause of the error.

Comment: I'd urge you to test this, but from what I can tell from the information provided in the question, the parentheses in the key are indeed cause or the *error*. The *warnings* about locale settings are independent of that issue, but most likely harmless anyway.

Comment: Any updates here? Can we close this as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96454/35864 or do we need to address anything else?

Comment: I'd say this is not exactly a duplicate, but - yes - we can close this issue for now. Thank you.